# when Device Time Setting is in 24h Formate Get time is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am having problem displaying proper date in my app. When user sets 24 hour format 'OFF' in his date time preferences..my app shows correct time. but when 24 hour format is set to 'ON' it shows nothing.

```
        NSString *FireDate_Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:00 %@",Hour_Str,Minute_Str,[[AM_PM_Btn titleLabel].text lowercaseString]];
        NSLog(@"FireDate_Str: %@ ", FireDate_Str);

//      FireDate_Str Formate: 02:02:00 am

        NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *wakeTime = [df dateFromString:FireDate_Str];
```

But i Got wakeTime is (null) When Device time Setting in 24h is ON.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss a"];
```

See [the unicode date formatting reference](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and [Apple's Date formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).